# Remove Legend default keyword "Stack" from MpAndroidChart

Tags: android, kotlin, mpandroidchart

I am using MpAndroidChart library for android. I am able to give different color for the region below and above of the limit line. but i am getting a keyword "Stack" in legend(please check the attached screen shot).
Without limit line  everything working perfectly. But if i am using limit line (red for region right of the limit line and green for  otherside )  i am getting two legend and keyword "Stack" is appending along with legend.

```
if (yAxisValue != null) {

var progressData = progressLayoutData

val barDatasets: MutableList<IBarDataSet> = java.util.ArrayList()

for (yValues in yAxisValue) {

    val entries: MutableList<BarEntry> = java.util.ArrayList()
    var i = 0f
    var isHaveLimitLine = false
    val colorList: MutableList<Int> = java.util.ArrayList()
    for (value in yValues?.dataSet) {

        if(progressData?.limitLine!=null && progressData?.limitLine!=0) {
            if (value > progressData?.limitLine ?: 0) {

                var differenceValue = value?.toFloat() - progressData?.limitLine?.toFloat()!!
                entries.add(BarEntry(i, floatArrayOf(progressData?.limitLine?.toFloat()!!, differenceValue)))
                colorList.add(fhuiManager?.getParsedColor(yValues?.color,context))
                colorList.add(fhuiManager?.getParsedColor(progressData?.limitExceedColor ?: "#FE2020",context))
            } else {
                colorList.add(fhuiManager?.getParsedColor(yValues?.color,context))
                entries.add(BarEntry(i, value?.toFloat()))
            }
            isHaveLimitLine = true
        }else{
            entries.add(BarEntry(i, value?.toFloat()))
        }
        i++
    }
    val barDataSet = BarDataSet(entries, "" + yValues?.datasetName)
    if(isHaveLimitLine)
        barDataSet?.colors = colorList
    else
        barDataSet?.color = fhuiManager?.getParsedColor(yValues?.color,context)
    barDataSet?.setDrawValues(false)

    // add to line data set
    barDatasets?.add(barDataSet)

}

return barDatasets
```

}
[Please see the screenshot of issue here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qx0UA.png)